# Does saying Shahada for first time make one a muslim or do I need to follow all the rules?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, shahada

I have been learning about Islam these past few months or so and I do believe there is no God but Allah, and Muhammad is the messenger of Allah. 
If I ever have a question I'll usually try googling it for help or ask Muslim friends. I've read a little bit of the Qur'an English translation from Pakistan.
 I was reading online that you have to say and believe in the Shahada from your heart in order to become a true Muslim. Long story short, I was at the store with my mom and she was just shopping and I was sitting and learning more things online and I saw some forums that said you could say Shahada by yourself and mean it and turn to a true Muslim at that moment. There was different stuff where I saw you have to shower/bathe to purify your body afterwards and that you have to have 2 witness but that these are more optional? 
Anyways I told myself, why wait, I could say it here and be considered a true Muslim (I know a shopping store isn't the best environment for this but I thought theres no reason to wait) I read it and meant it and I got really excited... I started kinda skipping/jumping towards my mom and I felt cheesy because I was doing childish moves (skipping/jumping) and I said outloud "I'm being lame" and I regretted saying that I was lame immediately because maybe I gave the wrong impression to Allah that I felt I was lame because I said Shahada which was not the case at all.
 I hope Allah knows my intentions are true and that I didn't mean any insult. And I wonder if Allah took my Shahada and am considered a true Muslim or am I supposed to wait longer until I fully understand the religion more (I still have a lot to learn).... I know In the future I will go and recite with 2 witnesses but for now I'm just hoping Allah knows my intentions that I want to be a true Muslim and didn't mean any insults.
 **I just wonder at what point would I be considered a true Muslim... Now or Once i begin praying and following all rules.**

Comment: Once you become a Muslim the prayer is a due on you. Scholars discussed whether one needs to say the two testimonies before praying or will he/she be a Muslim once he started praying as the prayer of a non-Muslim is considered as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Saying shahadah is the first and essential step towards Islam and once you did you are true muslim. But you have to know its meaning which imply that we are all slaves for Allah. We have to follow his commands as much as possible and stop doing anything haram. If we didn't do that at any time, wehave to repent and go again to the right way.